# Consuming last message in Apache Kafka topic (python) not working

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka

I've been trying to get the latest message in a Kafka topic with the following approach (kafka python version 2.0.2):

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topic', bootstrap_servers =['localhost:9092'],
                            value_deserializer = lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
                            auto_offset_reset ='latest',enable_auto_commit=False,
                            consumer_timeout_ms=2000)
```

And then consuming it with:

```
poll = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=2000, max_records=1)
consumer.seek_to_end()
messages = []
temp = []
msgs = []
[temp.extend(i) for i in poll.values()]
[ msgs.extend([i]) for i in temp ]
for message in msgs:
  message_data = {}
  message_data['partition'] = message.partition
  message_data['offset'] = message.offset
  message_data['key'] = message.key
  message_data['value'] = message.value
  message_data['processed'] = False
  print('Message data: '+str(message_data))
  messages.append(message_data)
print(messages)
```

However, I'm getting an empty array (messages). Can you provide any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeking to the end... You need to move back one offset if you want the last message, which you do with something like

```
offset = consumer.position(partition)  # TODO: loop over each partition from consumer.assignment()
consumer.seek(partition, offset - 1)
```

Note: Might need `-2` since position returns the *next record* to consume